# Info light on toolbar disappears when view is in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a navigation bar controller with a toolbar.  There is only one button on the toolbar in the left hand corner: Info light.  When I rotate the view to landscape, the toolbar is still there but the button is gone.

How do I make it stay.  I checked my struts for the toolbar in IB.  They are set to stay in the lower left corner of the toolbar.

I am testing on an iPod touch with base SDK of 4.0.

Here is the code:

```
UIButton *info = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
[info addTarget:self 
             action:@selector(infoTap:) 
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
/** Allocate and initialize the information button on the leftside of the toolbar.
 */
UIBarButtonItem *infoItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:info];
/** Use this to put space in before your info toolbar button.
   */
UIBarButtonItem *flexItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
/** Add buttons to the array.
   */
NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: infoItem, flexItem, nil];
/** Add array of buttons to toolbar.
   */
[self.toolbar setItems:items animated:NO];
/** Add the toolbar as a subview to the navigation controller.
   */
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

Any suggestions?

Amanda

Comment: Why are you using the UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace at all?  If the button is positioned on the left most side of the toolbar, you don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is correct for what you want to do, so the problem lies within supporting code.

A couple things I would check:
Is the enclosing view (self.navigationController.view) getting resized on rotation?

What are the struts and autoresizingmasks on self.navigationController.view?

What are the struts and autoresizingmasks on the UIToolbar?

(I'm not sure what you mean by: "I checked my struts for the toolbar in IB. They are set to stay in the lower left corner of the toolbar."  How can the toolbar stay in the lower left of the toolbar?).